# Find how many times each value from column A appears in column B in the same table

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm new to SQL, I'm learning from a free youtube MySQL course for beginners.

2 days ago I gave myself a problem and now I found a work-around, but perhaps there are better ways to solve it.

| emp_id | super_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | NULL |
| 101 | 100 |
| 102 | 100 |
| 103 | 102 |
| 104 | 102 |
| 105 | 102 |
| 106 | 100 |
| 107 | 106 |
| 108 | 106 |

emp_id marks each employee, super_id - their supervisor. I wanted to find how many subordinates each employee has.

This is just a problem for my learning purposes, it has no significance in the real world. If this is really easy and I'm overcomplicating, I'm sorry. I'm using a self-join, because it's just one table here.

I found this on google:

```
SELECT A1.A, COUNT(*)
  FROM Anonymous AS A1
  JOIN Anonymous AS A2 ON A1.A = A2.B
 GROUP BY A1.A;
```

After tweaking it like this it almost worked, except that it returns 1 subordinate for each employee that should have 0 subordinates:

```
SELECT emp1.emp_id, COUNT(*) AS Subordinates
FROM employee AS emp1
LEFT JOIN employee AS emp2
ON emp1.emp_id = emp2.super_id
GROUP BY emp1.emp_id
;
```

I've no idea why and how self-join works by the way... But it works for my task. After the following tweak it does everything that I wanted, BUT if there is an employee with exactly one subordinate, it will say he has none (I suppose). So it's not a real solution. And there might be a simpler or more elegant way to do it?

```
SELECT emp1.emp_id, IF (COUNT(*)>1, COUNT(*), NULL) AS Subordinates
FROM employee AS emp1
LEFT JOIN employee AS emp2
ON emp1.emp_id = emp2.super_id
GROUP BY emp1.emp_id
;
```

Result

| emp_id | subordinates |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 101 | null |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | null |
| 104 | null |
| 105 | null |
| 106 | 2 |
| 107 | null |
| 108 | null |

Comment: Trick is to count the rows from emp2 table only.

Comment: @Shadow can you provide an answer good sir? op already provided sample data and what they have tried.

Comment: @BagusTesa provided a duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow *scratch head* err, using a (inner) `join` will result supervisors without subordinates won't be shown. using `left join` and `count(*)` will give you exactly 1 subordinate for rows with `null` on the `employee2`. your dupe flag involves a `group by` on `name` column which we surely don't have. additionally, we need a self-join which the duplicate flag again, doesn't show example of. so, please enlighten me with something that works with op's sample data. thank you.

Comment: @BagusTesa no duplicate question has exactly the same column as the current one, that is an unreasonable expectation. Self join or join on another table is basically the same thing and the OP realised it needs a self join - that was not the question. What the duplicate shows is that the count is not on *, but on a column for the right hand side table.

Comment: @Shadow my bad, i can't see it that way earlier. i'm sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about using `COUNT()` on the right side of the left joined table?

```
select e1.emp_id,
       count(e2.emp_id) as subordinates
  from employee as e1
  left join employee as e2
  on e1.emp_id = e2.super_id
group by e1.emp_id
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/322VZ9CfYjMMtg8i81T2Dd/1

Comment: That appears to work with my data set. Thanks! now I need to wrap my head around this. At least this will no longer bother me!

Comment: Can't see his answer for some reason :)

Comment: no need for distinct.  the trick is that `count(*)` counts all joined sets of rows in each group while `count(expression)` counts non-null values for expression, so providing any column in e2 that can't be null will count numbers of times e2 was actually joined

Comment: @ysth yes, you are right

Answer (score -1):

You dont need join

```
 select e1.super_id, count(e1.emp_id)
 from employee as e1
 where e1.super_id is not null
 group by e1.super_id
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but unfortunately it seems that this solution has the same problem as my first proposed solution, it says people have 1 subordinate, while they should have none. I appreciate your time though.

Comment: This second solution that you propose only lists employees who have any subordinates, which is 3 employees, while I wanted a list of all employees.